# AucTeX - Turning inline mode into displaymath and vice versa

Tags: math-mode, emacs, auctex, inline

Usually, when redacting math stuff, I deal many times with the following situation : I have written some formula in a displaymath environment and, when compiling, realize it should look better inline ; then maybe return to the displaymath environment if inline is not satifying.

So I have something like

```
The presheaf
\begin{displaymath}
    F \colon C \to \mathsf{Set}
\end{displaymath}
is a sheaf.
```

When compiling, I realize I would prefer it inline. So I switch to

```
The presheaf $F \colon C \to \mathsf{Set}$ is a sheaf.
```

But it requires me to : erase the `\begin{...}` and the line break before it, insert a `$` instead, erase the `\end{...}` and the line break after it, and insert a `$` instead. Kind of long for such a current operation, especially when I change it to the way it was just after that.

Is there some key binding in AucTeX mode to turn a selected displaymath formula into a inline one, and vice versa ? Like a `C-u C-c C-e` (which changes the innermost environment).

---

**Edit.** I realize this is more a Emacs questions than a *TeX one, but I couldn't think of a better stackexchange to ask it.

Comment: You can use `\[...\]` for display math and `\(...\)` for inline math.  Then, the change is easier.  (Not sure if this comment applies to AucTeX)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I like `\begin{displaymath} ... \end{displaymath}` so I can easily change from `displaymath` to `equation` or `align` or whatever. Plus, `\(...\)` is kind of less readable than `$...$` in my opinion.

Comment: Then how about `\newenvironment{textmath}{$}{$}`?  Actually I think the already existing `\begin{math}...\end{math}` will accomplish what you want.  Then, just delete or add the words "display".

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yes, it would certainly do the job. However, if there is a emacs way to do it without changing the syntax, I would prefer it (to *un-inline* in the source things that are inline in the compiled file... it breaks a little the readability of the source).

Comment: A keyboard macro could certainly accomplish it...

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yes, this is what I ask. If this is part of AucTeX, I can't find the command. If it is not, how to define it ? (I'm not quite comfortable with emacs-lisp programming.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following function to your `.emacs`:

```lisp
(defun mg-LaTeX-swap-inline-display-math ()
  "Swap between inline math and display math."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (when (texmathp)
      (cond
       ((equal (car texmathp-why) "$")
    (goto-char (cdr texmathp-why))
    (delete-char 1)
    (push-mark)
    (search-forward "$")
    (delete-char -1)
    (exchange-point-and-mark)
    (LaTeX-insert-environment "displaymath"))
       ((equal (car texmathp-why) "displaymath")
    (LaTeX-find-matching-begin)
    (re-search-forward "\\\\begin{displaymath}[ \t\n\r]*")
    (replace-match "$")
    (LaTeX-find-matching-end)
    (re-search-backward "[ \t\n\r]*\n\\\\end{displaymath}")
    (replace-match "$"))))))
```

With this function, you can just leave the point inside the `displaymath` environment and issue <kbd>M-x</kbd> `mg-LaTeX-swap-inline-display-math` <kbd>RET</kbd> to convert the environment to an inline math, the other way round if you are between `$...$`.  Nothing happens in other cases.

You can also bind the function to your favorite shortcut.  For example, if you want to bind it to <kbd>C-c m</kbd> add the following code to your `.emacs`:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "latex"
    '(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-c m") 'mg-LaTeX-swap-inline-display-math))
```

Comment: When the `displaymath` environment is inside another environment and is indented, the command `(re-search-backward "[ \t\n\r]*\n\\\\end{displaymath}")` doesn't find the end of environment because of the leading whitespace. For me replacing that line with `(re-search-backward "[ \t\n\r]*\n[ \t\n\r]*\\\\end{displaymath}")` worked better.

Answer (score 0):

giordano’s solution above is excellent and helped me a lot, thank you. Here is my modification toggling between the environments `$`, `\(`, `\[`, `equation` and `align`.

```
        (defun LaTeX-change-surrounding-math-environment ()
          "Swap between inline math displays."
          (interactive)
            (save-excursion
            (when (texmathp)
              (cond
                ((equal (car texmathp-why) "$")
                  (goto-char (cdr texmathp-why))
                  (delete-char 1)      (insert "\\(")
                  (search-forward "$") (delete-char -1) (insert "\\)"))
                ((equal (car texmathp-why) "\\(")
                  (goto-char (cdr texmathp-why))
                  (delete-char 2)      (insert "\\[")
                  (search-forward "\\)") (delete-char -2) (insert "\\]"))
                ((equal (car texmathp-why) "\\[")
                  (goto-char (cdr texmathp-why))
                  (delete-char 2)
                  (insert "\\begin\{equation\}")
                  (search-forward "\\]")
                  (delete-char -2)
                  (insert "\\end\{equation\}"))
                ((equal (car texmathp-why) "equation")
                 (LaTeX-modify-environment "align"))
                ((equal (car texmathp-why) "align")
                 (LaTeX-find-matching-begin)
                 (re-search-forward "\\\\begin{align}[ \t\n\r]*")
                 (replace-match "$")
                 (LaTeX-find-matching-end)
                 (re-search-backward "[ \t\n\r]*[ \t\n\r]*\\\\end{align}")
                 (replace-match "$"))
                ((equal (car texmathp-why) "displaymath")
                 (LaTeX-modify-environment "equation"))
           ))))
```